# enable macro in a excel file programmatically using powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Macro excel implementation....

I tried following code but it doesn't work:

```
 OLEObject oleobject,lo_excel
 lo_excel = CREATE OLEObject

if lo_excel.ConnectToNewObject('Excel.Application') = 0 then

      lo_excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = 'false'
      lo_excel.Visible=false
      lo_excel.workbooks.Open('D:\EAC9A0001.xls')
      lo_excel.Application.Run('D:\tender_template.xls!allinone')
      lo_excel.Application.save()
      lo_excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close('D:\EAC9A0001.xls')
      lo_excel.Application.Quit()
      lo_excel.DisconnectObject()

      DESTROY lo_excel
  end if
```

Comment: Your example is closing a file on c: while it is opening the file on d: